# In Java, why does Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, language-design, math

Quite simply, I was aghast when I discovered one of my unit tests was failing because `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`!

Why would the language designers choose this, **what is the mathematical advantage**, and what are some alternatives I might consider in the future when dealing with edge cases?

Comment: Read up on two's complement.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know it well. I know the min is one farther from zero than the max. I'm still baffled that this is the chosen behavior, because I see no mathematical benefit.

Comment: Because what else would it possibly be? Zero? Java doesn't throw exceptions on integer overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are negative signed values stored?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239036/how-are-negative-signed-values-stored)

Comment: @Supuhstar: nothing comes for free, Java's chosen behavior yielded the best bang for the buck in the designers' opinion.

Comment: @whatsisname Why? What are alternatives and why are they less advantageous?

Comment: @Supuhstar The only viable alternative I see is throwing an exception for any kind of (signed) integer overflow (which would make java's choice of not supporting unsigned integers even more annoying than it already is).

Comment: If you "know it well" then you can demonstrate for yourself how negating `MIN_VALUE` produces `MIN_VALUE` -- at least in a language that limits you to N bits, and does not provide access to the carry bit or throw on integer overflow. As for the mathematical benefit, follow *gnat*s link.

Comment: @Supuhstar: You would know what those alternatives are if you "Know it well" as you said you did for two's complement.

Comment: Good find. Any decent programming language should raise an `arithmetic overflow exception`. And true, in .Net the overflow check is de-activated by default. Hope that you can activate it in Java also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that this is how twos-complement negation works. It's not overflow, and it
wouldn't be detectable without special circuitry in the processor (or equivalent checks in the
language runtime).

## How Twos-Complement Arithmetic Works

I'll start with the number line, in binary, limiting my wordsize to 3 bits:

```
011 =  3
010 =  2
001 =  1
000 =  0
111 = -1
110 = -2
101 = -3
100 = -4
```

Inside the computer, there is an [Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) circuit
that can combine two bits and produce a result plus carry bit. These circuits are chained together,
so that the processor can add two entire words. The carry bit from this addition is exposed to via
a processor status register, but *is not normally available to high-level languages*.

Some examples:

```
 2  010      2  010     2   010
 1  001     -1  111     2   010
== ====     == ====    ==  ====
 3  011      1 C001    -4   100
```

Let's look at those examples individually:

- 2 + 1 = 3, just like you'd expect. Both the addends and the sum are within the range of positive integers
  for our word size.
- 2 - 1 = 1, again just like you'd expect. Internally this operation sets the carry bit, indicating that the
  addition overflowed the word size. If we were using unsigned numbers, this would be a problem, but with
  twos-complement numbers it's OK.
- 2 + 2 = -4, which is definitely *not* what you'd expect. However, note that the carry bit remains unset.
  To detect overflow in this case, you'd have to check that two signed inputs resulted in an output with a
  different sign.

So why isn't overflow checked? The simplest answer is cost.

At the level of the hardware, addition is unsigned (at least on the three processors that I've programmed).
Detecting integer overflow would require a separate set of opcodes for signed math, which would mean more
transistors, which could be more profitably used elsewhere. In the earlier days of computing that was a
huge concern; today, maybe not so much but almost everyone is OK with how math is implemented.

At the level of the language, cost is still a factor. There is the runtime cost of checking every signed
operation for overflow, but there is also a programmer cost: imagine having to wrap *all* expressions
(even a *for* loop) with a try/catch. The .Net runtime apparently gives you the option of enabling this,
while Java [explicitly does not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.3).

## How Twos-Complement Negation Works, and why -MIN_VALUE equals itself

In prose: twos-complement negation flips all of the bits in a number and then adds one.

I use a prose definition because that's almost certainly how it actually works in the hardware (although I'm
not a hardware engineer, so can't say for sure, plus different architectures might use different techniques).

Let's see what happens with our 3-bit words:

```
100 = MIN_VALUE
011 = all bits flipped
100 = after adding 1
```

Note that there's no carry involved, although you could check for sign of value and result. However, that
again would require special circuitry and/or runtime-level checks, *to catch a result that will happen
almost never*.

## What Are Some Alternatives, and Why Aren't They Used

One alternative is [ones-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), in which negation is
simply inverting all bits. The ones-complement number line for a 3-bit word looks like this:

```
011 =  3
010 =  2
001 =  1
000 =  0
111 = -0
110 = -1
101 = -2
100 = -3
```

According to the linked Wikipedia article, there were machines using ones-complement arithmetic; I never used
one. Again, I'm not a hardware engineer, but I *believe* that you need separate operations for addition and
subtraction with ones-complement (in addition to separate operations for unsigned math), which again runs into
the problem of cost.

The Wikipedia article mentions the problem of "end-around borrow," which may have been an issue with the actual
computers that used ones-complement math, but I don't think is a necessary problem. I believe that the carry
bit could also serve as a borrow bit.

The bigger problem is that you have two values for zero. Which is going to cause programmers to create a *lot*
of off-by-one errors when counting, or is going to require a *lot* of special-case code in the language
runtime (eg: a `for` loop that knows when it crosses 0 that it has to skip to 1/-1).

Another alternative is to use the high-order bit just as a sign bit, with the low-order bits being the same
between positive and negative:

```
011 =  3
010 =  2
001 =  1
000 =  0
100 = -0
101 = -1
110 = -2
111 = -3
```

This is how [IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) works. It makes sense when
your primary operations are assumed to be multiplication and division, not so much for addition and subtraction.
And it still has the issue of two zeros.

## Commentary

To me, this question is identical to questions that express outrage over the fact that 0.10 cannot be represented
by a floating point number: both indicate a belief that digital computers should be able to exactly represent the
real world. Or, in other words, that computers operate according to the laws of mathematics.

I can understand this belief; what I can't understand is the outrage that people express when the belief is shown
to be false. A few moment's reflection should make it apparent that the belief *cannot* be true: computers work
with finite quantities, whereas mathematics deals with continuous relations (I was about to say that everything
in the real world is continuous, but figured that someone would bring up quantum mechanics).

Faced with this fundamental truth, computer designers -- and language designers, and application programmers --
have to make trade-offs. You might not like the particular tradeoff, but you should seek to understand it rather
than simply complain about it. And once you understand the tradeoff, you can look for an environment that made a
different tradeoff.

Answer (score 3):

The mathematical reason is that Java implements "arithmetic modulo 2^32". (Or, rather, the CPU implements arithmetic modulo 2^32, and Java exposes the implementation.)

What this means is that, as far as Java's `int` type goes, numbers that differ by a multiple of 2^32 are considered the same. This means:

- If a number is too big, you subtract 2^32 until it's not too big.
- If a number is too small, you add 2^32 until it's not too small.
- The numbers 2^31 and -2^31 are considered the same, since they differ by 2^32.

Now, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is -2^31, so its negation is -(2^31), which is 2^31. However, in arithmetic modulo 2^32, this is considered the same as -2^31, so that's what you get out.

So what are the *advantages* of arithmetic modulo 2^32? Some of them are...

- It's easier to implement in hardware than any alternative.
- It allows applications to use the same instructions for both signed and unsigned arithmetic.
- It's frequently useful in mathematical applications.

The reason that *Java* uses arithmetic modulo 2^32 is presumably that Java is simply exposing the way that the CPU implements arithmetic. This is vastly easier and more efficient than any alternative.

Comment: I wouldn't say "the CPU implements, and Java exposes the implementation". If you had a CPU using one-s complement, the Java implementation would still have to implement two-s complement behaviour, no matter how hard it is.

Comment: @gnasher729 - yes, but Java was designed to use 2s complement precisely because all common CPU designs also use that.  You could also try running Java on a 21-trit ternary computer, but then you'd have to figure out what to do with 6,000,000,000ish values that computer can represent in its registers that Java doesn't let you use.  Java was designed to run on real computers that actually exist, and not arbitrary computers that could theoretically exist.

Answer (score 1):

Because most computer hardware these days uses 2's complement arithmetic to implement signed integer maths.

```
               00 00 00 00 = 0
00 00 00 01 to 7F FF FF FF = 1 to 2147483647
80 00 00 00 to FF FF FF FF = -2147483648 to -1
```

2's complement arithmetic actually works just like unsigned arithmetic; the difference is in how you interpret the results.  This makes it easier for microprocessor designers to implement both without redesigning the arithmetic units.

Since the underlying hardware works that way, so does Java.

Comment: If you're going to answer this, you should at least show _why_ `MIN_VALUE` turns into itself when negated.

Comment: @kdgregory That's just an unfortunate feature of 2's complement where attempting to negate the most negative integer causes an arithmetic overflow.  The overflow just happens to wrap around to give the most negative integer again.  *For anybody wondering, the quick way to negate a number in 2's complement is to flip all the bits, then add 1.*

Comment: @kdgregory: That doesn't really need showing. Just look at the values (MIN_VALUE = -2^31, MAX_VALUE = 2^31 - 1) and do the maths. You'll also find that MIN_VALUE * k is 0 if k is even, and MIN_VALUE if k is odd if you do the maths; negation is just the special case that k = -1 (odd).